# Algorithm for determining equivalency classes

Tags: algorithm

Rather general question. I have a list like this:

```
A B  
A C  
C A   
D E  
F G   
E F  
C L  
M N
```

and so on.

What I want to do - is to figure out all the relations and put everything that's related in a single line. The example above would become:

```
A B C L   
D E F G  
M N
```

so that every letter appears only once, and the letters that related to each other are on in one line (list, array, whatever).

Is this some kind of known problem with a well-defined algorithm? Does it have a name? Sounds like it should be. I'd assume some kind of a recursive solution should be in place.

Comment: Close voters: this is a perfectly well-defined question about graphs (finding connected components) that OP just didn't know the name of. It is not "too broad".

Comment: Formally speaking what you are looking for is [equivalency classes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_class) from an [equivalence relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation). This is a fair question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to solve this is to use an undirected graph G=(V,E). Each pair in your input represents an edge in E, and the output you want is the [connected components](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_%28graph_theory%29) of G. There are some great Python graph modules such as [NetworkX](http://networkx.github.io/).

**Demo**

```
>>> data
[['A', 'B'], ['A', 'C'], ['C', 'A'], ['D', 'E'], ['F', 'G'], ['E', 'F'], ['C', 'L'], ['M', 'N']]
>>> import networkx as nx
>>> G = nx.Graph()
>>> G.add_edges_from( data )
>>> components = nx.connected_components( G )
>>> print "\n".join([ " ".join(sorted(cc)) for cc in components ])
A B C L
D E F G
M N
```

Answer (score 2):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory)

(but don't worry too much about their suggested algorithms, because you have a list of edges, whereas they assume that you don't.)

Let's call a letter a Node, and a set of nodes a Component. You need to produce a set of Components given a list of edges.

First, map Nodes to Components:

```
Map<Node, Component> map.
```

Then:

```
For each edge E:
    For each node N in E (i.e. all two of them):
        Component c = map.get (N)
        if c doesn't exist then:
            c = new Component
            map.put (N, c)

        c.add (N)

For each Component C in map.values ():
    Print (sort C's nodes)
```